# Datatables Sorting with checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm having trouble in sorting of my datatable. 
I have 4 checkbox for different category. but it is possible to have 2 or three categories in one data so i want to sort it depends on what my checkbox sorting select. the problem is for example, I select category 1, it will only shows data with the category 1 only but the other data with category 1 and 2 is not. what i want is even if i select category 1 only in checkbox, it will display data with category 1 and 2

Here's my code for the checkbox

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li><small><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="filterme()" value="Ethereum" name="Category"><img src="<?php   bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icon/data-eth.png">Ethereum</label></small></li>
  <li><small><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="filterme()" value="Neo" name="Category"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icon/data-neo.png">Neo</label></small></li>
  <li><small><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="filterme()" value="Waves" name="Category"><img src="<?php   bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icon/data-wave.png">Waves</label></small></li>
  <li><small><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="filterme()" value="Others" name="Category"><img src="<?php    bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icon/data-other.png">Others</label></small></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the data in table

```
<td class="category" hidden >
    <?php if ( get_field('sponsored_eth') == true ): ?> Ethereum <?php else: ?> <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( get_field('sponsored_neo') == true ): ?> Neo <?php else: ?> <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( get_field('sponsored_wave') == true ): ?> Waves <?php else: ?> <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if ( get_field('sponsored_other') == true ): ?> Others <?php else: ?> <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

And Here's my Jquery Code:

```
function filterme() {
    //build a regex filter string with an or(|) condition
    var types = $('input:checkbox[name="Category"]:checked').map(function() {
      return '^' + this.value + '\$';
    }).get().join('|');
    //filter in column 0, with an regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
    otable.fnFilter(types, 1, true, false, false, false);

    //use radio values
    var frees = $('input:radio[name="free"]:checked')[0].value;
    //now filter in column 2, with no regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
    otable.fnFilter(frees, 2, false, false, false, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For complex search you need to use custom search functions, see [Search plug-in development](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) or [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

For example:

```
function filterme(){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search = [ 
        function( settings, data, dataIndex ) { 
            var success = false;

            /* Apply your search conditions here */

            return success; 
        }
    ];

    table.draw();
}
```

Please note that you need DataTables 1.10.x for the following code to work.

For DataTables 1.9.x, see [Plug-in row filtering functions](http://legacy.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering).

Also DataTables 1.10.x is backward compatible with DataTables 1.9.x.